# How can I avoid the space character between the defined text and a comma?

Tags: macros

How can I avoid the space character between the defined text and a comma? See blue arrow.[image: Output of TeX Code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\cst}{\colorbox{white}{\textcolor{red}{\textsf{Quelle Universum AX1}}}}
\begin{document}
Call this think, say, \cst, and do other thinks like runing LATEX. Have a look at the output.
The output looks ne, so perhaps one of the other packages you have loaded has caused the problem. One by one try each of the packages you have in \cst problem document, in the
same order. If adding the package has no effect on the output,
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a precise reason for `\colorbox`?

Comment: Is there any reason for the white background and `\colorbox` here?

Comment: @egreg it's to make space after `\cst` :(

Comment: Of course it would be nice when I could use a color for the background. But first of all I would be happy if I can **specify labels** for _definded special word combinations_ and TeX does his job as usual. I do not want using different labels in different situations of what coming after.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't absolutely need a box, get rid of it as Draggluon proposes.  However if you need to keep it, the key is to set `\fboxsep` to `0pt`, scoped so that it doesn't affect any other boxes in the document.  The `\fboxsep` defines a buffer space added around the content before enclosing it in a box.  One also needs to use `\cst{}` with the added empty group, if one wants actual space following the invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\cst}{{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{white}{\textcolor{red}{\textsf{Quelle Universum AX1}}}}}
\begin{document}
Call this think, say, \cst, and do other thinks like runing LATEX. Have a look at the output.
The output looks ne, so perhaps one of the other packages you have loaded has 
caused the problem. One by one try each of the packages you have 
in \cst{} problem document, in the
same order. If adding the package has no effect on the output,
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why might keeping the box be important?  If your background color were different than white, or if the box overwrote something underneath of it.

[image]

Without the `\fboxsep` reset to `0pt`, one can see where that unwanted space comes from:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're making a box, this is the extra space. Delete `{\colorbox{white}` in the command.

```
\newcommand{\cst}{\textcolor{red}{\textsf{Quelle Universum AX1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution: in this case the background colour that the OP wanted (white) happened to be the same as that of the page, but what if they wanted a different one? E.g. say `\newcommand{\cst}{\colorbox{yellow}{hello}}`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR It's a good point, but I provide solution for his code. And the backgroud it's white.

Comment: But without \colorbox{white} there is no space between "Quelle Universum AX1" and "problem"

Comment: @asdfgh see any latex tutorial you need `\cst\ problem` as the space after `\cst` just terminates the command, it does not add space to the output.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Then I must usually add \ after \cst, but not if there is a "," or "." or ":" or "?". Is it not possible that this decision does TeX?

Comment: @asdfgh or always use `\cst{}`  as `\cst{}, foo` and `\cst{} foo` both work.